# opkg install error - wfopen no such file or directory

Tags: opkg

I have followed instructions to create an `.ipk file`, the `Packages.gz` and host them on a web server as a repo. I have set the `opkg.conf` in my other VM to point to this repo. The other VM is able to update and list the contents of repositories successfully.

But, when I try to install, I get this message. Can you please describe why I am getting this and what needs to be changed?

```
Collected errors:
 * wfopen: /etc/repo/d1/something.py: No such file or directory
 * wfopen: /etc/repo/d1/something-else.py: No such file or directory
```

While creating the .ipk, I had created a folder named `data` that had a file structure as `/etc/repo/d1/` with the file `something.py` stored at `d1` location. I zipped that folder to `data.tar.gz`. And, then together with `control.tar.gz` and 'debian-binary`, I created the .ipk.

I followed instructions from here:
http://bitsum.com/creating_ipk_packages.htm
[http://www.jumpnowtek.com/yocto/Managing-a-private-opkg-repository.html](http://www.jumpnowtek.com/yocto/Managing-a-private-opkg-repository.)
http://www.jumpnowtek.com/yocto/Using-your-build-workstation-as-a-remote-package-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the directory called `/etc/repo/d1/` does not exist on the target system. If you create the folder manually, and try installing again, it probably will not fail. I'm not sure how to force opkg to create the empty directory by itself :/

**Update:**
You can solve this problem using a `preinst` script. Just create the missing directories on it, like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /etc/repo/d1/

# always return 0 if success
exit 0
```